# Concurrent queue with pthread implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a multi-threaded queue implemented with pthread. Since I came up with the code based on several tutorials from Internet, I would like to make sure there is no logic error in my code:

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue {
public:
    ThreadQueue() {
        pthread_mutex_init(&m_qmtx, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&m_condv, NULL);
    }

    ~ThreadQueue() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_qmtx);
        m_queue.clear();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_qmtx);
    }

    void push(T t_data) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_qmtx);
        m_queue.push_back(t_data);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_qmtx);

        pthread_cond_signal(&m_condv);
    }

    T front() {
        T ret;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_qmtx);
        while (m_queue.empty()) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&m_condv, &m_qmtx);
        }
        ret = m_queue.front();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_qmtx);
        return ret;
    }

    void pop() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_qmtx);
        if (!m_queue.empty())
            m_queue.pop_front();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_qmtx);
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_queue;
    pthread_mutex_t m_qmtx;
    pthread_cond_t m_condv;
};
```

Comment: This seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why you need `m_condv` and `pthread_cond_signal(&m_condv);` after `push`?

Comment: @MM. To make sure the queue is thread safe.

Comment: @user2207811: Do you mean just a `mutex` is not enough to make `push` thread-safe?

Comment: @MM. My mistake. I use pthread_cond_t to make sure whoever pull data from the queue do not have to *busy wait*

Comment: Are you aware that C++11 has introduced threads in the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big problem I can see with your code is that it is not exception safe. As long as your `deque` operations don't throw it's not a problem but if (or rather when, it's just a matter of time) they will throw, then your mutex will stay locked and then you'll be stuck.

Example:

```
void push(T t_data) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_qmtx);
    m_queue.push_back(t_data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_qmtx);

    pthread_cond_signal(&m_condv);
}
```

Here, `push_back` can throw for various reasons (not enough memory, T's copy-constructor throws, ...) and if it does, `pthread_mutex_unlock` never gets called.

The best solution to make your code exception safe is to write a RAII wrapper for `pthread_mutex_(un)lock`. Something like:

```
class MutexLock {
public:
    MutexLock(pthread_mutex_t& mutex)
        : m_mutex(mutex)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(m_mutex))
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not lock the mutex.");
    }
    ~MutexLock() { pthread_mutex_unlock(m_mutex); }
private:
    pthread_mutex_t& m_mutex;
}
```

Then you can rewrite your `push` function (and the others) like that:

```
void push(T t_data) {
    {
        MutexLock lock(m_qmtx);
        m_queue.push_back(t_data);
    } // note: braces to enforce *lock* scope, for identical results to your code
    pthread_cond_signal(&m_condv);
}
```

**Note:** As you can see, I also added error handling for `pthread_mutex_lock` in the wrapper's constructor (another problem in your current code: when a function returns an error code you **need** to handle it!). In the destructor it doesn't really matter though, because (a) if the destructor runs it means the wrapper was constructed successfully so your lock holds the mutex (and you will be able to unlock it safely), and (b) a destructor should not throw so there's nothing you could really do anyway even if the unlock failed.

**More reading:** For more information on exception safety (which is an essential concept in C++), see the excellent Herb Sutter's series [Guru Of The Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/index.htm), he has a number of articles about exception safety (specifically, issues # 8, 21, 56, 59, 60, 61, 65 and maybe others I missed). You may also want to read about RAII.

### Alternatively: C++11

As @qdii mentioned, if you can use C++11 then you will probably be interested in replacing all the `pthreads` stuff with the new standard equivalents (`std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, ...) which have at least two advantages: (a) unlike `pthreads` they are portable, and (b) you don't have to bother so much about correctly implementing exception safety since the STL takes care of most of it (but you still have to use the correct idioms, like `std::unique_lock` for holding mutex locks -- the equivalent of my lame `MutexLock` RAII wrapper except the standard one is actually well thought out).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanations and clear examples!

Comment: @user2207811 You're welcome. I just added a last section to expand on qdii's comment about C++11, so I'm posting this comment to make sure you don't miss it. ;)